# Access fusionAuth-app UI from outside container (external access)?

Tags: docker-compose, fusionauth

I am using the following docker-compose.yml for deployment cloned from following https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/installation-guide/docker

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
# Un-comment to access the db service directly
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  search:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=fusionauth
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=${ES_JAVA_OPTS}"
# Un-comment to access the search service directly
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - search
    restart: unless-stopped
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  fusionauth:
    image: fusionauth/fusionauth-app:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
      - search
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/fusionauth
      DATABASE_ROOT_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      DATABASE_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      FUSIONAUTH_MEMORY: ${FUSIONAUTH_MEMORY}
      FUSIONAUTH_SEARCH_SERVERS: http://search:9200
      FUSIONAUTH_URL: http://fusionauth:9011
    networks:
     - db
     - search
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9011:9011
    volumes:
      - fa_config:/usr/local/fusionauth/config

networks:    
  db:
    driver: bridge
  search:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data:
  es_data:
  fa_config:
```

I am unable to access the fusionAuth UI screen from http://localhost:9011 or http://fusionauth:9011

How can I access the UI welcome screen from outside docker container? Is there any
`enableExternal: true` env variable available for docker-compose.yml?

Is there a way to test or ping the fusionAuth App server to make sure it's up and running other than using docker ps -a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an error with the docker image. An updated docker image was released hours after this question was asked, and that resolved the issue.

More details here: https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-containers/issues/47